# Teradata SQL MAX function and duplicate rows

Tags: sql, max, teradata

My original report returns 3 records for account ABC, 1 with an approved status and 2 with a suspended status.  The only difference in these lines is the status and billing number.  All other data is identical.

I'm trying to create a variation of this report that would return 1 line for Account ABC with a column that displays the count for approved accounts and another column with the count for suspended accounts.

In the new report, there would be an Approved Accounts column with a value of 1 and a Suspended Accounts column with a value of 2.

I'm using a MAX function to return only 1 line.  The issue I'm having is that 2 records with the suspended status are identical except for the Billing Number.

If I remove the billing number from the SQL then the results only return 1 suspended and 1 approved account.  I need the SQL to return 1 line with 1 in the approved column and 2 in the suspended column

Here is some sample data:

```
Acct#    Bill#    Name    Location   Status  
ABC      Bill1    ABC Co   123456   Approved
ABC      Bill2    ABC Co   123456   Suspended
ABC      Bill3    ABC Co   123456   Suspended
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need "conditional aggregation":

```
select Acct#, Name, Location, 
   sum(case when Status = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) as Approved,
   sum(case when Status = 'Suspended' then 1 else 0 end) as Suspended
from ...
group by 1,2,3
```